# comunication between parent and child class python

Tags: python, parent-child

Does anyone know how i can get the name of an object with a class function?

I want to use this because i have a class that is supposed to have multiple players in a list, and get their cordinates
object that wants to give their cordinates:

```
import math

class Pixel:
  """Represents a posision in a grid with a x posistion, a y position and
  a character, the x and y position are saved in one tuple"""`

  def __init__(self, char='#', pos=(0, 0)):
    assert type(char) == str
    assert type(pos[0]) == int and type(pos[1]) == int
    self.pos = pos
    self.x = self.pos[0]
    self.y = self.pos[1]
    self.char = char

  def __str__(self):
    return self.char

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.char
    # possible debug repr 'Pixel object with
    # char = ' + str(self.char) + ' and pos = ' + str(self.pos)`


class TestObject(Pixel):

  def __str__(self, parent):
    return '+'
```

The parent object wants to know what `self.pos` is from the`TestObject` (the parent has a list with different testObjects) is there a way for me to give the `TestObject` the name of the parent object when i am creating it so that he can push that information (`parent.funcname(position)`) I need it for a function that doesn't return values.

if anyone knows another way to get `TestObject.pos` to my parent object please tell too, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your instances of `TestObject` a reference to the parent. This could be done via the `__init__` method of `TestObject`. This way however, the parent has to be known at the time of the instance's construction. I would make it an optional (keyword) parameter and implement a setter method. For example:

```
class Pixel:

  def __init__(self, char='#', pos=(0, 0), parent=None):
    assert type(char) == str
    assert type(pos[0]) == int and type(pos[1]) == int
    self.pos = pos
    self.x = self.pos[0]
    self.y = self.pos[1]
    self.char = char
    self._parent = parent

  def set_parent(self, parent):
    self._parent = parent


class TestObject(Pixel):

  def somemethod(self):
    position = 0
    # do what ever you need to do here
    if isinstance(self._parent, Pixel):
      self._parent.set_value(self)
```

When you add an instance `obj` of `TestObject` to the list in the parent object, the parent object should call `obj.set_parent(self)` to set itself as the object's parent.

Here is an example for a parent class:

```
class PixelList:

  def __init__(self):
    self._pixels = []

  def add_pixel(self, pixel):
    self._pixels.append(pixel)
    pixel.set_parent(self)

  def set_value(self, pixel):
    # do stuff here
    position = pixel.pos
```

If you then call `obj.somemethod`, your parent object's `set_value` method is called with the pixel as argument. In the `set_value` method you can thus access any information of the pixel you like (e.g. `pixel.pos`).